# Android Unity Ads are True but they are not showing

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, ads, unityads

I have a problem.

My Ads are not showing on my Android Mobile.

So i added UNITY ADS to Android Project. 
I followed the steps from unity  INTEGRATION (ADS) https://unityads.unity3d.com/help/monetization/integration-guide-unity

And same codes,....

When i Play the game in Unity Project. i get this

UnityAdsEditor: Initialize(17XXX79, True);
UnityEditor.Advertisements.UnityAdsEditor:EditorOnLoad()

i exported the game on my ANdroid device and no ads are showing. 
Why?

I also deleted all my AAR files. 
if i put my AAR files back i'm getting a ERROR about ... AdS license or something like that.

Can someone tell me how to fix this???
Please someone help me.

Thank you very much.

Comment: You deleted the AAR plugins files which the C# API is calling to show ads but you expect it to work? That's like removing your car engine and expecting the car to start. If you get any with your AAR files present, create a new question with that error.

Comment: Hello, Thank you for replay. i Moved ALL my AAR files back to    UnityProject/Game/Assets/Plugins/Android.       Now i'm getting that error back... IOException: Failed to Move File / Directory from 'Temp/StagingArea\android-libraries\com.google.android.gms.play-services-ads-license-11.8.0\classes.jar' to 'Temp/StagingArea\android-libraries\com.google.android.gms.play-services-ads-license-11.8.0\libs\classes.jar'.                         there is more text... + 3 errors

Comment: Create a new question with that error. You may want to delete this question too. Just make sure to post the complete error in your new question

Comment: Hello, i fixed the error  by clicking Assets > Play Services Resolver > Android Resolver > Resolve